# Spring Security authentication principal as UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth2 client credentials flow with Spring Security and i'm able to obtain an access token driven by the oauth_client_details table.

The issue is that when the token is issued I see that the userAuthentication is null so it returns the principal as a string.  Looking at OAuth2Authentication:38 here :

> `public Object getPrincipal() { 
>           return this.userAuthentication == null ? this.storedRequest.getClientId() : this.userAuthentication
>                 .getPrincipal();    }`

From the docs -

```
An OAuth 2 authentication token can contain two authentications: one for the client and one for the user. Since some OAuth authorization grants don't require user authentication, the user authentication may be null.
```

I am using my own user details service and returning a UserPrincipal.  This works for form login and http basic without issues.  However with OAuth2 authentication the principal is a string instead of UserDetails.

Comment: Ever figure this out? Having the same issue